# Connection problema to specific IP

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, networking, mtr

Sometimes, like twice a year a have problems of connectivity from my server to an api server. And only to that api server. Other third party services we use were working fine.

I am not so good on the networking subject. So I want to know the reason of this problem. And the best way to solve it or handle it when it happens.

Follows the mtr result on the link.

http://notepad.cc/GUicheVV